# How do I add margin to just background image to textbox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

this is my style to add background image to textbox, i am using jquery UI datepicker

```
background: url("../Images/DatePicker.png") no-repeat scroll right center white;
```

but i want to set rightmargin to textbox border, how could i set margin in background?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `background-position` to set this. Using margin will affect the entire containing element. In the shorthand `background` property you've set, it's the second to last two values. Also, strictly speaking the `background-color` property should be set first. Try this:

```
background: white url("../Images/DatePicker.png") no-repeat scroll 35px center;
```

This will position the background image 35px from the left edge of the containing element. You may need to amend the value - I just guessed.

Comment: is it working in any resolution of computer ? cause i set textbox with in %

Comment: You can set the background position as a % of the total width too. Try `70%`

Comment: background: white url("../Images/DatePicker.png") no-repeat scroll 70% center;} ==> it is not working